# How do I create a data frame from a list that contains different elements in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas column like this

```
train['finally'].head(5)


0    [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...
1    [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
2    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3    [2, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, ...
4    [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, (3, 1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
```

I want to use it to create a separate pandas data frame using this column

I tried using this

```
visits_df = train['finally'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(',')))
```

and this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(train.visits.str.split(' ').tolist())
```

I tried splitting on commas and space, but the same result

but the problem is that there are some elements inside the column that are tuple like this `(3, 1)`

I tried splitting on commas and space, but the same result.

```
0   [0  0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0]  NaN
1   [0  0   0   4   0   0   0   5   0   0   ... 6   0   0   4   0   0   (2  4)  0   0]
2   [0  0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   ... 5)  0   3   0   0   0   0]  NaN NaN NaN
3   [2  0   7   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   5   0   0   6   0   0]  NaN NaN
4   [0  0   0   0   7   0   0   (3  1)  0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

it splits tuples into separate columns and I see extra columns and there should only be 143 columns

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Are the individual items actually lists, and (in that case) is each list the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `apply` + `pd.Series`. No need to convert to `str`.

```
df
              finally
0    [9, 5, 16, 4, 1]
1  [7, 2, 16, 30, 13]
2    [7, 5, 3, 2, 16]
3  [5, 15, 11, 23, 5]
4     [3, 1, 1, 4, 6]
5   [3, 14, 4, 0, 14]
6   [5, 1, 10, 21, 5]
7  [9, 17, 11, 10, 8]
8   [6, 11, 20, 6, 6]
9    [21, 4, 3, 4, 9]

df['finally'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))

    0   1   2   3   4
0   9   5  16   4   1
1   7   2  16  30  13
2   7   5   3   2  16
3   5  15  11  23   5
4   3   1   1   4   6
5   3  14   4   0  14
6   5   1  10  21   5
7   9  17  11  10   8
8   6  11  20   6   6
9  21   4   3   4   9
```

Note that converting to string and splitting on comma, you risk splitting up the data in the tuples as well, I'm guessing you don't want that.

---

Note that if you have a column of *strings* to *begin with*, it'd be a good idea to parse them to python objects first, using `ast`.

```
import ast
df['finally'] = df['finally'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

And then follow the process outlined above.

Comment: and now I feel so dump 
Thanks a lot, it's perfect